# apt server certificate verification with a valid certificate

Tags: apt, repository, ssl

I'm attempting to make a private apt repo. Its going to be served over https and its located at https://repo.signalvine.com. It is also going to be using basic auth, which I setup as `deb https://username:password@repo.signalvine.com/ dev non-free` as indicated [here](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/513/Restrict_Access_To_Your_Private_Debian_Repository). When I attempt to update the apt cache I get:

```
Err https://repo.signalvine.com dev/non-free amd64 Packages                          
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

When I connect using curl (`curl https://repo.signalvine.com`) from the same machine, curl states that `SSL certificate verify ok`. I've also tested repo.signalvine.com using [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=repo.signalvine.com) and it doesn't find any problems. What do I need to do in order for apt to validate my certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had the intermediate certificates out of order. Web browsers and ssllabs were fine with that but, it appears that apt cares about the ordering of the intermediate certificates.